# How can I close gaps between curtains temporarily?

Tags: curtain-rail

In day, I want sunlight and pull curtains apart. In night, I pull them together, and want curtains overlap in middle. But I open window for fresh air ventilation, and wind blows my curtains apart, and light pollution enters gap in middle.

I don't know how sew. I don't want sew any thing on curtains. I take down curtains and wash them every 2 months.

I thought adding [Bias Tape](http://www.amyscreativepursuits.com/2019/06/how-to-quickly-and-easily-add-belt.html) with [Fabric Glue](https://www.onlinefabricstore.net/makersmill/no-sew-methods-stitch-witchery-vs-glue/), then tying curtains together with a belt or string. Will this work? Any simpler idea?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ar these pictures of your actual curtains, or are they just random pictures of curtains you posted just in case no-one here knows what curtains look like?

Comment: @brhans "random pictures". But curtains hook curtain rail in different ways! I want picture my issue...two curtains that don't overlap in middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Clothespins

A package of [clothespins](https://amzn.to/32fWaZK):

[image]

will do the trick. Depending on the length of the curtains and how tightly you want them pulled together, you would probably use between 3 and 6. You can remove them totally when open or leave them clipped to one side.

No sewing! No gluing!

Comment: Clothespins are fun. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=fun+with+clothespins

Answer (score 1):

**YOU CAN SEW**, it is not difficult, you do not need a sewing machine. A needle and some thread. I do it, if i can do it you can do it. Or a friend/friends kid, Think laterally.

[Sewing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvzMMcKHVR4) OR [Sewing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkz6qadODb0)

**Magnets**. You can sew some little magnets in small pouches of fabric and then sew them on to the back side of the curtains. You would need to have them at the same height on both curtains so when the curtains are closed the magnets can touch.

**Hook and loop fasteners** (*Velcro*) would be another option. Sew it onto the curtains.

I have curtains behind my Television and i never open them. I have them fastened with [safety pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_pin).

Comment: very good idea using magnets